# How is __proto__ different from [[Prototype]]?

Tags: javascript, prototype

My understanding on the concept: objects come with a hidden property called `__proto__` that provides reference to function object's prototype property. When I create an empty object and log it into the console, I see the property within the object is `[[Prototype]]` instead of `__proto__`. Can you provide any insight or correction to my understanding on the concept?

Answer (score 2):

`[[Prototype]]` refers to an *internal slot* of objects - values which are held in the JS engine, but not directly exposed to the running JavaScript. See [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) for details from the specification.

The value contained in an internal slot can often be retrieved if there are methods that deliberately expose it.

For another example of an internal slot, consider the values of a Set:

```js
const set = new Set();
set.add('someValue');
```

The `someValue` is not directly visible on the Set, but it can be accessed through methods which run native code, and that native code accesses the internal slots of the Set to see what it contains - for example, with `Set.prototype.has`.

In the case of `[[Prototype]]`, the value in that internal slot can be retrieved by invoking the `__proto__` getter, [which does](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-get-object.prototype.__proto__):

> 2. Return ? `O.[[GetPrototypeOf]]()`.

eventually accessing and returning the `[[Prototype]]` internal slot.

Also, `__proto__` is deprecated - you should prefer to use `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `Object.setPrototypeOf`.

Comment: This didn't answer my question unfortunately. I don't know who is in charge of monitoring this forum but for someone to close my other similar question for a different input is highly unprofessional.

Comment: What about my answer doesn't make sense to you? I tried to explain what the `[[Prototype]]` is (an internal slot), and `__proto__` (a deprecated getter/setter that interfaces with the `[[Prototype]]`) I don't know what your complaint about professionalism is coming from, sorry...

Comment: I asked for insight and correction on my understanding on the concept. What you gave me is what I can read from the official document. I'm sure your answer is correct but it didn't help with my understanding on this particular topic. You alluded to the 'internal slot.' What does that do? And 'a deprecated getter/setter that interfaces with the [[Prototype]]'? I can read that from a Wikipedia page. I was n't trying to be ungrateful here. But for someone to close my other questions is infuriating.